# Split MainFrm with CDockablePane

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have two Cdockablepane and I want it to act like CSplitWnd.
I am not using splitwnd right now because I need docking feature..
[Current UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAulG.png) 
Green is MainFrame and Blue, Yellow is Dockablepane I created.
Red one is overlapped part I want to get rid of.
I have yellow.DockToWindow(&blue, CBRS_RIGHT); in my code
but I don't know what make that overlapping part..
and black part I want fill MainFrame just with blue and yellow pane.
[Target UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gTd8.png) So I want my code look like this.
I tried by changing yellow and blue's CRect() on create() but it seems like not the answer.
or changing the style.....
So please if anything comes in mind tell me..

My...I wanted to describe better..
Thank you.

===========================================================================
 Following is the code in the CMainFrame MFC. It creates CDockablepane yellow&blue when MainFrame is created.

```
 int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
 {
 if (!blue.Create(_T("HORIZONTAL ROBOT PANE"), this, CRect(0, 0, 800, 500), TRUE, ID_DOCKABLE_LEFT,
    dwViewStyle | CBRS_ALIGN_LEFT))                                         
  {
    return FALSE; 
}                                 
blue.SetMinSize(CSize(800, 400)); 
blue.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
DockPane(&blue, AFX_IDW_DOCKBAR_LEFT);

if (!yellow.Create(_T("VERTICAL ROBOT PANE"), this, CRect(0, 0, 650, 500), TRUE, ID_DOCKABLE_RIGHT,
    dwViewStyle | CBRS_ALIGN_RIGHT))
{

    return FALSE; 
}
yellow.SetMinSize(CSize(400, 400)); 
yellow.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY); 
DockPane(&yellow, AFX_IDW_DOCKBAR_RIGHT);
yellow.DockToWindow(&blue, CBRS_RIGHT);
}
```

Comment: It will be easier with the code

Comment: Override in CMainFrame::OnSize(,,) and set the size for yellow and blue rect, That should work.